# Uniquely Identify UDP Connection - Multiple Connections from same IP

Tags: c++, udp

I'll start by saying that currently my server identifies based on sender IP, that is the IP of the client.

Now I am programming a game server (just for practice) and this got me thinking how do I uniquely identify a client if they are on the same IP. (Two players open a connection on the same machine / same network so the outward IP is the same).

I've searched for an answer both on google and here and gamedev.net but am unable to find what I am looking for, likely because I do not know the correct terms to query for.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated, especially in regards to efficiency and best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure with UDP, but for TCP it's the client's **IP and his port**. A TCP connection is generally identified by 4 numbers: IP and port for both client and server. Since your server's IP and port are fixed, that leaves client IP and port for identification. Now for UDP: Here you don't have such a thing like *connections*, you simply send and receive single packets. I'm not sure if the client is allowed to switch ports between packages, but I guess so.

Comment: Would the port number not be exactly the same? If I open a client for a game with the port 100, sending to server port 100, then both clients would be sending from the same outward IP and the same port, no?

Comment: There are server ports (what you're talking about) but also client ports (which are infamous, since you don't care about them usually). A client usually chooses a random port when connecting to a host.

Comment: There is nothing like connection in UDP, the UDP packet contains the information about the sender IP and port so you need to read that and identify different UDP clients. IP will be same but ports will be different.

Comment: I did consider this but it would be possible for two clients to be launched at exactly the same time and have the same port. A possible implementation is to have the server assign a unique "connection ID" and send it to the client upon first connection but I am unsure if this is best practice.

Comment: Clients from same machine can never share same ports.

Comment: Not the same machine but multiple machines on the same network. Either I am not grasping something fundamental here or there is the possibility of overlap occurring between outwardIP and port.

Comment: Connection identification IS the purpose of ports. The 4-tuple Source IP + Source Port + Dest IP + Dest Port will uniquely identify a connection (or pseudo-connection for UDP). If it wasn't the case, the internet would have been broken by now. Literally all the firewalls/NATs/smart routers in the world are relying on this. About "multiple machines on the same network", this is a NAT case. If the 4-tuple ID wasn't valid, your "multiple machines on the same network" wouldn't have been possible in the first place.

Comment: *"the possibility of overlap occurring between outwardIP and port"* This is handled by the client network's NAT by the so-called [Port Address Translation (PAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Establishing_two-way_communication).

Comment: I see! It was the case of me misunderstanding something fundamental then. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "connection" term in all stuff related to UDP, but it is common that an application that initiates a UDP socket maintains the same source port over the time, **so you could identify it by source IP-port**.

There is some stuff related to maintain communication between a client inside a NAT router (in NAT-UDP the client is the first host that send a UDP datagram to another host and trigger a new connection tracking entry) and a server.

This "connection tracking" is only for allow traffic from outside to inside, making a "temporal" relationship (with a timeout), that probably will not be used anymore (only once) sometimes.

If the server doesn't use the same destination port in outcoming datagram as source port in incoming one, the router won't send the datagram to the host inside NAT.

Best regards.